# Prove: $A \cap(B\cup C^*)=(A\cap B)\cup C^*$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do you prove this mathematically, when $C^*$ is the complement of C? I know from drawing a Venn diagram that this equation should hold.

$A \cap(B\cup C^*)=(A\cap B)\cup C^*$

Thanks!

Comment: What is $C*$? $$$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sensible" statement to consider is:

> **Conjecture.** For all sets $X$, the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $X$ satisfies the
>   following [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28mathematics%29).
>
> $$A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪C$$

**This is false.**

E.g. take $A=\emptyset_X$ and $C=X$. Then $A \cap (B \cup C) = \emptyset_X$, while $(A \cap B) \cup C = X$.

However, it can be salvaged by adjoining the condition that $C \subseteq A,$ which isn't altogether surprising since this rules out the case $A=\emptyset_X$ and $C=X,$ as well as all similar cases.

> **Proposition.** For all sets $X$, the power set of $X$ satisfies the following [quasi-identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiidentity).
>
> $$C \subseteq A \rightarrow A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪C$$

*Remark.* In the language of [lattice theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29), this just says that the power set of $X$ is always a [modular lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice).

*Proof.* Consider a set $X$ and subsets $A,B,C$. Assume $C \subseteq A$. Then $A \cap C = C.$ So we may argue as follows:

$$A∩(B∪C)=(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cup C$$

Of course, this is just the proof that every distributive lattice is modular.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$A \cap(B\cup C^*)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C^*)$

So if $A \cap C=\emptyset$, then $A \subset C^*$ and the equality is holds.